# Marketing Cloud FTP --> Automatic Delete Functionality

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, ftp, bulk-delete

Is there a way to setup a rule so that your Marketing Cloud FTP will delete a file older than a certain date?

Comment: Talk to support. They can usually adjust your retention period on the FTP. I believe by default it should be at 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom retention periods will no longer be applicable for the customer's accounts.

Marketing Cloud will retain your files on Marketing Cloud FTP for at least 21 days. Any file that exists on the Marketing Cloud FTP, that is older than 21 days, will be eligible for removal; and Marketing Cloud may remove it any time after 21 days. There is no assurance or guarantee that a file older than 21 days will be removed.

If you require a shorter retention period, for your files, you should use your provided FTP account to remove the files from your FTP location. Marketing Cloud will no longer apply new custom file retention periods to FTP directories.

[Updated Information from salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2020_platform_ftp_retention.htm&type=5)

Answer (score -1):

The files are retained for 21 days, You can talk to support to change this date.

> Any file that is older than 21 days is eligible for removal, and we
> can remove files any time after 21 days. However, there is no
> assurance or guarantee of removal for files older than 21 days.

[Source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336497&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: Support will NOT adjust this time frame anymore